# (Javascript) ¿Cómo determinar las posiciones de varios elementos en una matriz y guardar la fila y la columna respectiva en otra?

Tags: javascript, array

Quizá no se entiende muy bien en el título, pero lo explicaré mejor aquí.
Yo tengo una matriz 4x4, que recoge valores introducidos por el usuario. Así:

```
var nums = new Array(4);
var mayor = 0; 
nums = [new Array (4), new Array (4), new Array (4), new Array (4)];
var pro = 4*4;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) //Lee los valores que el usuario pone.
{
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (pro < 2)
        {
            nums [i][j] = parseInt (prompt("Escribe "+pro+" número."));
        }
        else
        {
            nums [i][j] = parseInt (prompt("Escribe "+pro+" números."));
        }
        --pro;
    }

}
```

Como pueden fijarse, yo quiero conseguir los valores más grandes introducidos por el usuario. Digamos que el usuario introdujo las siguientes entradas:
[image: Entradas introducidas por el usuario]

O lo que es lo mismo

```
nums = [[432,54,546,543],[65,432,654,432],[65,234,65,99999],[99999,99999,654,99999]];
```

Para acortar la explicación digamos que el número mayor es 99999:

```
mayor = 99999;
```

Entonces, con todo esto asumido, busco hacer una nueva matriz que me introduzca la posición exacta (fila y columna separada) de cada elemento que sea igual a 999999:

```
var mayoresPos = new Array (2);
mayoresPos = [[2,3,3,3],[3,0,1,3]]
```

Como se ve arriba, la posición de las filas y la de las columnas, están puestas en diferentes arreglos dentro del arreglo mayoresPos.

Entonces, ¿cómo puedo hacer que me den las posiciones ordenadas de esa forma?
No soy muy experto en Javascript, apenas lo estoy practicando, y agradecería bastante que me ayudaran con esta cuestión que me tiene bastante rato pensando en cómo poder realizarlo. (El objetivo principal para separarlos es para poder introducirlos en un  con más facilidad, pero si obtengo esos datos ya tendré la parte de la implementación lista.) De nuevo, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongamos que tienes ya la matriz, entonces sólo te falta recorrer cada elemento y quedarte con las coordenadas que apunten al valor que buscas:

```js
const nums = [
 [432, 54, 546, 543],
 [65, 432, 654, 432],
 [65, 234, 65, 99999],
 [99999, 99999, 654, 99999]
];

const coordenadasX = [];
const coordenadasY = [];
const pares= [];

const valor = 99999;
for (let y = 0; y < nums.length; y++) {
 const fila = nums[y];
 for (let x = 0; x < fila.length; x++) {
  if (fila[x] === valor) {
   coordenadasX.push(x);
   coordenadasY.push(y);
    //otra opción para guardarlos
   pares.push({x,y});
  }
 }
}

const resultado = [coordenadasX, coordenadasY];

console.log(resultado);

console.log(pares);
```

Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es guardar las coordenadas de la misma donde el valor sea 99999, recorriendo todas las posiciones.